# Python-cloudant slow query speed?

Tags: python, cloudant

When I do a query to my database with python-cloudant using 3 selectors, the query takes ~15 seconds to complete and print results. When I put a limit of 2 in (see code below), the result appears very quickly, but after 2 takes much longer. There are currently ~190,000 documents in this database. Am I missing something that can speed this up?

```
query = cloudant.query.Query(db,selector={'_id': {'$gt': 0},'userid':{'$eq':'56900'},'year':{'$eq':'[2011]'}},fields=['_id','userid','year'],sort=['_id'],limit=2)
for doc in query()['docs']:
    print doc
```

(The goal of this query is to get all records from the userid "56900" that contain "[2011]" in the year field and sort them by the _id)

Comment: Do you have indexes set up for the userId field? If not chances are you are forcing the DB to do a full scan over all the documents.

Comment: @rhyshort Maybe not correctly. I added the following but it does not speed up the query:

    "json: userid, year"
{
 "type": "json",
 "def": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "userid": "asc"
   },
   {
    "year": "asc"
   }

Comment: Maybe try removing the `'_id': {'$gt': 0}` from your query, iirc that would trigger a full scan since your looking at the _id field, which all docs have

Comment: @rhyshort that worked, now it is very speedy, thank you!

Comment: Cool, I'll just write it up as an answer to make it easier for others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments on the question. The reason why it is slow, is that the `'_id': {'$gt': 0}` part of the selector is causing all documents to be scanned to see if that match the rest of the selector.  Removing this clause and having the fields `userid` and `year` indexed have a massive increase.